# EC2 host type for a DynamoDB batchWrite call

Tags: amazon-ec2, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb, java.util.concurrent

I have a requirement to bulk upload an excel sheet to a DynamoDB table and the maximum number of rows are 200,000. The website for bulk upload will be used less frequently, so we can assume there are only 1 - 2 bulk uploads being processed at a given time. In the backend, I am using Apache POI API to parse the excel sheet into DynamoDB Items.

Because we can only send up to 25 items in a `batchWriteItem` call, the currently latency is around 15 minutes (900 seconds) to completely upload all the 200,000 items. Hence I am planning to implement multi threading to execute multiple `batchWriteItem` API calls in parallel. Can you help me understand which EC2 host types are best suited for multi-threading for this purpose.

Any references will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, multi-threading would be helped by using an Instance Type that has multiple CPUs.

However, you are describing behaviour that is waiting on network rather than CPU. Therefore, it is likely that the operation you describe is not being heavily impacted by CPU Utilization.

The best way to answer your question is to recommend that you **experiment with different instance types** to find the one that is best for your application's combination of needs:

- Pick an instance family (eg m5) and try a few different sizes
- Compare this against another family (eg c5) to see whether the improved performance is worth the extra cost
- Monitor the application to find the bottleneck, which would either be RAM, CPU, Network or Disk access

Please note that smaller instances have less Network bandwidth, so you might need to choose a larger instance type to avoid being throttled on network bandwidth. This might result in excess CPU that isn't being fully utilized.

Comment: Thanks John for the suggestions. I will experiment with different instance types